# azure service bus queue read bulk message using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to fetch messages in bulk from azure service bus queues using node js azure package, Now i am able to fetch message using set-interval.is there any other way to fetch messages in bulk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Service Bus REST API does not currently support receiving batches, so there is not a valid implementation in this library. Part of the reason is that the REST implementation is not particularly performant, and it is much better to use AMQP. If you are looking for something with better performance, I would take a look at this library:

https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10

Related issue on **[`github`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/1992)**

Also you can try this **[`out`](https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/azure_service_bus_send_message_batch.asp)**.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to peek specified number of messages from a ServiceBus queue in bulk.  Messages can be received from a queue using the receiveQueueMessage method( which supports receiving only one message at a time) on ServiceBusService in Node.js Azure package. By default messages will be deleted from the queue as they are read, however when received in peeklock mode by setting the optional parameter `isPeekLock` to true can prevent deletion

Pre- Requisites to use `Azure` ServiceBus:

1. `Node.js` `Azure` package, which can be installed using command, `npm install azure`
2. An environment variable `AZURE_SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING`, with information required by the Azure module to connect to the `ServiceBus` queue

Below is a sample code to receive 10 messages,

```
//Import the module

 var azure = require('azure');

 //Create ServiceBusService object

 var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService();

 var receivedMessages = [];

 while(i<10){

    serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage('myqueue', { isPeekLock: true }, 
    function(error, lockedMessage){

        if(!error){
           // Message received and locked    
           receivedMessages.push(lockedMessage)    
        }
    }
 });

 Console.log(receivedMessages);
```

Comment: @Manish and Ezhilarasi any idea how we can release the lock on the fetched message so it will be available for other consumers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [@azure/service-bus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus) package which has an api to receive messages in batches. This takes the max batch size and max time to wait as input. You will either get the number of messages you asked for or the number of messages that were fetched within the provided time. Checkout the sample that [receives messages in a loop](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/%40azure/service-bus_7.0.0/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/javascript/receiveMessagesLoop.js).

```js
const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
const queueReceiver = sbClient.createReceiver(queueName);
const messages = await queueReceiver.receiveMessages(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus

Here's a sample code for you create a receiver object and then get multiple messages:

```
let receivingMode = ReceiveMode.peekLock;//Or receiveAndDelete
let sbClient = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);  
let subscriptionClient = this.sbClient.createSubscriptionClient(topicName, subscriptionName);
let receiver = this.subscriptionClient.createReceiver(receivingMode);
let messages = await this.receiver.receiveMessages(maxMessageCount, maxWaitTimeInSeconds);
```

For example if maxMessageCount = 10 and maxWaitTimeInSeconds = 60 it means the function will return 10 messages as soon there are 10 and if it waited for 60 seconds it will return anyway.